# how to edit the user profile

Tags: django

Hi guys I am new to Django.
I wants that when I login to my account there is a edit button which shows me a form of some fields which I can edit.

I am confused how the data is saved to the same user profile.

So can anybody tell me how is that possible.Can show me it with one example

With my profile.html I can see my profile and on click on edit button I can edit my profile

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>User_id: {{ drinker.user_id }}
    <p>Name: {{ drinker.name }}</p>
        <p>Birthday: {{ drinker.birthday }}</p>
        <p>first_name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>     
        <p>Users: {{ user.username }}</p>
    <p><a href="/edit/">Edit Profile</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit function**

```
 def Edit(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') 
        drinker = request.user.get_profile()
        context = {'drinker':drinker}
        return render_to_response('edit.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

**Edit.html**

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#birth" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="/edit1/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="register_div">
    <p><label for="name">Name:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" value="{{ drinker.name }}"></p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="birthday">Birthday: {{ drinker.birthday }} </label></p>
        <p>Choose new date of birth</p>
    <p><input type="text" value="" id="birth"></p>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

On edit1 edit request function works

```
def EditRequest(request):
    #if request.method == 'POST':
       #form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)

  #if request.user.is_authenticated():
    #return render_to_response('hgdhg')
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = EditForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            user=User.objects.create_user(usere_id=form.cleaned_data['user_id'])
         #user.save()
            drinker=user.get_profile()
            drinker.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
            drinker.birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            drinker.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
         else:
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/f/') 
    else:
            return render_to_response('f')#,{'form':form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**this editrequest doesn't work ?**

Comment: Start with [storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Comment: I have studied.
But there is no way given how to edit a profile.It just shows the profile to you.And I can see my profile and now i wants to edit that one

Comment: so if you can help me please do

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried? Editing a profile is just like editing anything else, by using forms or a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to execute to edit a user's profile:

1. Find out which user is logged in (read up on [user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/))
2. Check if the user has a profile or not; use the normal django query mechanism for that.
3. If the user has a profile; populate a ModelForm with the instance of the profile (see [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) in the manual)
4. Display the form to the end user just like any other form.
5. When the user submits changes, do the normal form validation and save the object to the database.

Here is some code that does steps 1-4:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from myapp.models import UserProfile
from myapp.forms import UserProfileForm 

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    try:
       user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
       # this user has no profile
       return redirect('/error')

    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
    return render(request,'profile_edit.html',{'form':user_profile_form})
```

The `UserProfileForm` class:

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

Comment: for that I have to create a userprofile model or I can use my model

Comment: You can use any model, I used `UserProfile` because that is what is used in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Comment: ok. I created the profile.html file and it gets the previous values.
but when I modified them and click on submit button. it doesn't do anything.I think it needs a fuction which will work on submit button

Comment: Yes, you do - and you need to write it yourself. SO is not to have other people do your work for you. We are here to help, but you need to show some effort on your end as well.

Comment: Hi guys my problem remain the same.
The code which I have given to you in question with the help of that i can get the user profile the problem is modified data is not saved.

And the method which you guys told are only tells how to get the user data nobody tells how to save that data.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) first, try with your best effort, and if you don't understand _something specific_, then come back with what you tried and what went wrong and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

pass the instance of user along your model form

```
  user = User.objects.get(user_name = username)
  form  = Registrationform(instance=user)
```

and render this form to your template

Comment: i am sorry @burhan i couldn't see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Example i did before:

```
@login_required                              
def lexuseditform(request,userpk):
    if Adult.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        adult = Adult.objects.get(user=request.user) # load existing Adult
    else:
        adult = Adult(user=request.user) # create new Adult
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = AdultForm(request.POST,instance=adult) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            form.save()
            redirect_url = reverse('lexusedited',kwargs={'userpk': request.user.pk})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url) # Redirect after POST
    else:
           form = AdultForm(instance=adult) # An unbound form
    return render(request,'lexus/lexuseditform.html', {'form': form})

@login_required                              
def lexusedited(request,userpk):
    return render(request,'lexus/lexusedited.html')
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi guys my problem remain the same.
The code which I have given to you in question with the help of that i can get the user profile the problem is modified data is not saved.

And the method which you guys told are only tells how to get the user data nobody tells how to save that data.